# Connection refused with postgresql using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "45.32.1XX.2XX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Here,I've open my sockets.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      11516/postgres                
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*       LISTEN      11516/postgres
```

I googled that I should modify this `pg_hba.conf`，but in my `postgresql`root files, I didn't find this file at all.

Also I've succeed in connecting my another server.

Thanks.

Here,I've modified the `pg_hba.conf`,updated this`host all all 218.3.A.B trust` and reloaded.But it didn't work either.

Comment: Under what operating system is running PostgreSQL?

Comment: in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your netstat output shows that postgres is listening on `127.0.0.1`, but your error suggests you are trying to connect to `45.32.1XX.2XX`.  I am pretty sure you have already diagnosed your problem.

You will need to modify the `listen_addresses` setting your `postgresql.conf` file (*not* `pg_hba.conf`).  The `postgresql.conf` file is found in your postgresql data directory, which is often something like `/var/lib/postgresql/data` or `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.

The `listen_addresses` parameter is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot.Finally i append this `listen_addresses = '*'` into `postgresql.conf`.And it works well.

Answer (score 6):

```
1. Modify two configure files
# vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
 Replace the line:
listen_addresses = 'localhost'  -> listen_addresses = '*'
# vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
 Add the line at the very end:
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
(If IPv6:
host all all ::/0 trust) 
2. Restart the database service
# service postgresql restart
3. Disable the firewall
# rcSuSEfirewall2 stop
# chkconfig SuSEfirewall2 off
# chkconfig SuSEfirewall2_init off
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. But after modification of the `pg_hba.conf` file, it worked. Also, i'm on postgresql 11

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting listen_address line and introducing '*' worked for me. In the beginning was working without it (gunicorn with Postgres database)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure that you've started postgress with  `systemctl start postgresql`