# Running docker container fails to connect to remote DB with psycopg2, but works in python interface

Tags: postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I am running a dockerized version of my application by simple way of docker run (not running in host network mode). The goal is to make a database connection with the psycopg2 module. I am making two connections, one to a source database and one to a target database. The parameters are passed as values that are read from environment variables I pass to the container. The issue is the first connection runs fine without issue, but an exception as always thrown on the second connection object.

Relevant code snippets:

```
        conn_source = pg.connect(database=SOURCE_DB, 
                                        user=SOURCE_USER, 
                                        password=SOURCE_PASS, 
                                        host=SOURCE_HOST, 
                                        port=int(SOURCE_PORT),
                                        cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        

        conn_source.set_session(autocommit=False)
        cur1 = conn_source.cursor()

        conn_target = pg.connect(database=TARGET_DB,
                                        user=TARGET_USER, 
                                        password=TARGET_PASS, 
                                        host=TARGET_HOST, 
                                        port=int(TARGET_PORT),
                                        cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/work-dir/app/dummy_app/app.py", line 99, in getPostgresConnectors
    conn_target = pg.connect(database=TARGET_DB,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "dummy_host" (192.28.2.111), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dummy_user"

connection to server at "dummy_host" (192.28.2.111), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dummy_user"
```

This is a seemingly (to me) unexplainable bug. If I simply switch the source and target parameters, I still run into the same problem with the second connection call throwing an error, so it doesn't seem to be a specific database configuration problem. The strange thing is when I run the same code in the Python interactive shell, I have no issues creating two back to back connections. What could explain this?

Note: I would be unable to edit the pg_hba.conf files as I do not manage them.

Comment: This is really too weird. Have you checked whether you have any sort of connection number limit either on the DB or related to `psycopg2` ? Also just as a test, try using the exact same parameters for the two connections just as a test, see what happens

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have tried that and run into the same issue as described. The second connection call throws an error. The only way I have been able to get around it is to point the source and target to my host local DB and edit the pga_conf to trust all connections, but clearly that is not a feasible solution.

Comment: Are each of the connections pointing to a different port?

Comment: @JorgeCampos no they are all pointing to the default postgres port, 5432

Comment: I hope `dummy_host` is changed by you to mask the actual data ?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have one PG server and inside it two DB schemas, you mentioned early that setting it to trust all connections works, this is probably something related to the listening configuration of PG... see if something in this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929258/connection-refused-with-postgresql-using-psycopg2